# sudoer file allow command for docker not working

Tags: docker, sudo

I have a set of docker run commands in my sudoer file. Some of the commands work fine with sudo, but others are not being accepted with statement "Sorry, user xxx is not allowed to execute '/bin/docker run ....'

A few things to note:

- Script syntax is just "sudo docker ...", sudoer file command syntax is "/usr/bin/docker" but for some reason the message is using "/bin/docker"
- the command that has the error seems to also only appear with error "Error: no such container..." after the sudo error message

Comment: The commands are being executed in the script by "eval $cmd" syntax.

Answer (score -1):

There were new line characters in the sudoer file it was believed.